# Plotting with transparency in matlab, creates weird dark lines

Tags: matlab, transparency, alpha, fill

For some unknown reason, I cannot create a plot with transparent areas (using the `'FaceAlpha'` property on a `fill()` object) for my data. I'm using MATLAB R2016b and R2017a 64bit. There is no error message, just the ugly black lines as shown in the following image:

[image]

Could you please copy&paste the following code and tell me if its working for you?
https://gist.github.com/felixsc1/7a1398185a428d964d50e96f8cbc3edc

I read somewhere that MATLAB's `opengl` renderer has problems with long decimals, but I tried to round my numbers to fewer digits and still have the same issue.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained instead of asking others to copy-paste code from your github account.

Comment: *"Could you please copy&paste the following code and tell me if its working for you?"* MATLAB R2016b on Linux (64-bit) https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFJiQ.png